# \n or <br\> is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am setting value of hiddenfield from code behind in vb.net

```
If(condition)
hdmodulename.Value =Dt_Module.DefaultView(0).Item("vModuleCode").ToString() +
 "-" + Dt_Module.DefaultView(0).Item("vModuleName").ToString()

Else

hdmodulename.Value = hdmodulename.Value + "'\n'" + Dt_Module.DefaultView(0).Item("vModuleCode").ToString() + "-" + Dt_Module.DefaultView(0).Item("vModuleName").ToString()
End If
```

now alert in javascript
i code like below:

```
alert('You cannot select ' + document.getElementById('<%=hdmodulename.ClientID%>').value);
```

Output :

> '\n' is printed inseted of new line

so what is the probem??
Thanks A ton in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with **Environment.NewLine** for VB.net

as below:

```
Dim value As String = "[First" + _
        Environment.NewLine + _
        "Second]"
```

will return

```
[First
Second]
```

Answer (score 1):

As for web pages, break lines with `<br>` or `<p></p>` tags. You can also Use `Environment.NewLine` with VB.

For JS use `\n' for the line break -`

```js
alert("some text\nmore text in a new line");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a vb expert, but shouldn't it be "\n" instead of "'\n'"? 
The one in the vb code have both double and single.

Comment: i tried this also but it gets same impact and in alert there is still \n instead of getting new line